# Hover on one element to affect the div before it not after it

Tags: html, css

I want to make a `<div` b on hover to affect `<div>` a. I have seen code for the reverse using (+)

```css
#a:hover + #b {
    background: #ccc
}
```

```html
<div id="a">Div A</div>
<div id="b">Div B</div>
```

But is there away to affect the opposite? Div B affecting Div A rather then A affecting B?

Comment: No...not yet. Perhaps in CSS Module 4

Comment: Sorry it got messed up. To clarify   
I want to make a div b on hover to affect div a. I have seen code for the reverse using (+)

Comment: In pure CSS, you can't. You could do some sort of hack using `:before` but that's rarely much of a consolation. JS is the only sure-fire way of achieving this.

Comment: No just two div's next to each other. I have link and span with an arrow. I want the arrow to move when you hover over the link (which it does) but I would also like when you hover over the arrow to have the link color change as it does when you hover.

Comment: Utkanos - Ok I will look into it.

Comment: @HashemQolami sorry, we must have been editing at the same time. It happens.

Comment: With pure CSS? No. With JavaScript? Yes.

Comment: Similar [issue here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510960/cant-change-background-color-of-another-element-on-hover/) which needs a *granduncle* selector :)

Comment: CSS tricks can fake it , http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vtsnC/ not to use really :)

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned, this isn't feasible as a CSS solution at this point in technology. You'd need to rely on Javascript.

Here is a jQuery solution for you:

```
$('#b').hover(
    function(){ $('#a').addClass('yellow') },
    function(){ $('#a').removeClass('yellow') }
)
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/ZFz73/3/)**

Comment: Thanks for this, but for some reason I cannot get it to work. Maybe because I am using a div class? This was close when I added a border element, but color did not work       $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".research_arrow").hover(function () {
        $(".research_link").css("color:#000000");
    });
    $(".research_arrow").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".research_link").css("color:#ffffff");
    });
});

Answer (score 1):

Selectors Level 4 draft defines the [subject](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject) of a selector, which allows you to use

```css
!#a + #b:hover {
    background: #ccc
}
```

However, AFAIK browsers don't support it yet.

And also note it's a feature of the [complete](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#complete-profile) Selectors profile, so it isn't extremely performance sensitive.

Comment: I've been waiting for that for too long...